# Vb.net: Start reading file when match found

Tags: regex, vb.net, streamreader

Trying to figure out how to NOT start reading from the beginning with stream reader but start reading once {Characters} is found. There are a lot of lines before this that I don't want to read. I am having trouble starting to read at {Characters} before I use regex to start matching results.

```
Function ReadFile()
        Dim mapping As New Mapping()
        Dim ShouldRead As Boolean
        Dim P As String
        Dim m As Match
        Dim reader As New StreamReader("..\..\..\FileName.myp", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
       
        Do 'I am trying to not start reading from the beginning but start reading at a line that is structured like this - {Characters}. 
            Dim input As String = reader.ReadLine()
            If input.Contains("{Characters}") Then ShouldRead = True
            If ShouldRead Then
                line = reader.ReadLine
            End If
            line = reader.ReadLine
            If line Is Nothing Then Continue Do
            m = Regex.Match(line, "^\[(\w+)\]")
            P = m.Groups(1).ToString()
            mapping.P = P
End Function
```

Comment: How many lines in total are we talking?

Comment: Maybe less than 500. Or, instead of starting to read at that line, could regex match {Characters}, then start reading. I would still need help with implementation either way. Trying to think of ways.

Comment: At 500 lines I would `File.ReadAllLines()` and then just run through the array looking for your matches.

Comment: You have no choice but to read the preceding data one way or another. Consider if someone  told you to start reading a book from the first place that a particular word appeared. How would you know where to start? You'd have to read from the beginning to find the word, right? Code is not magic. It's just an implementation of logic - the same logic that we apply to everything else in our lives.